# getElementById not showing up

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use getElementById to duplicate information in a page and it is not showing up. I included the script in the IDX-subheader (under the folder IDX-main):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById('IDX-detailsField-address'); 
var newElem = elem.cloneNode(true);
newElem.setAttribute('IDX-detailsField-address', 'IDX-details-address');
var before = elem.nextSibling;
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, before);</script>
```

I have set the copied element so that it has a different id(IDX-details-address).Added the div but I don't see the content of the div anywhere.

```
<div id="IDX-details-address"></div>
```

The script works in http://jsfiddle.net/BR72b/. 
The website is http://austinhometeam.com
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried debugging the javascript and if there is any javascript error or anything strange?

Comment: Didn't you mean `.setAttribute("id", "whatever value here")`? Or more easily - `.id = "whatever value here"`

Comment: I'm sorry....it should be  .setAttribute("id", "whatever value here"). I edited that and it is still not working..

Answer (score 1):

First, setAttribute is being used improperly. When you do setAttribute the first argument must be a type of attribute and the second must be the value of that attribute.

Secondly, you should be creating a new element rather than passing an element via reference. The best way to do this would be by using cloneNode() which will save all the attributes, and even children of the node.

If I understand your question correctly this would be a solution:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('IDX-detailsField-address');
var newElem = elem.cloneNode(true);
newElem.setAttribute('id', 'IDX-details-address');
var before = elem.nextSibling;
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, before);
```

When using cloneNode be aware that it will copy the ID of the element. When there are duplicate IDs on a page, only one will be usable.

Comment: Hi David,thanks for replying. I did have the cloneNode element in my script but I missed it when I was copying and pasting in here. I did change the .setAttribute to 'id' and couldn't understand why it still doesn't show up.